# Sync legend values across grouped dygraphs

Tags: r, data-visualization, shiny, dygraphs

The `group` function in `dygraphs` is particularly useful for a series of related plots if you want to x-axis zoom in unison.  I was looking for a feature or parameter that would also allow the mouseover legend values to be synchronized across the grouped `dygraphs`.  I see some functionality in the package relating to `mouseover`, however nothing with x or y coordinates in R.

This would be for use in a `shinyapp`.